# ElasticSearch min_score tuning

Tags: elasticsearch

I have seen a lot of posts suggesting against the use of min_score functionality. But it's important for my use case to display only high-quality results. Is there a way I can have the _score returned from elasticsearch be customized to a cosine similarity score between 0 and 1? Or get a good estimate of a good match. Currently, the same query gets different scores depending on the size of the data, thus making it difficult to set a min_score. What's the best way to limit results? My ES scores range from 7 to 55.

Comment: Before you try to rearrange the score range 7-55 into 0-1, take a look at this link https://discuss.elastic.co/t/limiting-the-relevancy-score-of-all-the-searched-documents/48123/11 Again why do you think score between 0 and 1 would be more accurate/relevant/high-quality as compared to what you observe now? Any artificial way of changing or calculating your score can influence the results and you may not have correct representation of order of results based on `_score/relevancy`.

Comment: `Currently, the same query gets different scores depending on the size of the data` That is because that is how relevancy is calculated. I'd suggest going through this link to see how `_score` is calculated. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html

Comment: Thanks for the response @Kamal. I don't want to rearrange the range from 7-55, I have read that ElasticSearch using a Vector Space model to calculate the cosine similarity between the query and the document. So i was wondering if there is a way to get that cosine score? Only cause it would make it easier to set a threshold. All i really want is to establish a threshold to filter out documents which are not high quality.